# Phonegap app does not run on iPhone iOS 7

Tags: ios, cordova, requirejs

I'm trying to run a phonegap(3.3.0)+requirejs app on actual device iPhone 5s iOS 7.0.6. It runs perfectly on simulator as expected but doesn't show anything on the device.

here's my data-main file for requirejs.

```
require(["fastclick", 'backbone', 'app/router','app/namespace'], function (FastClick, Backbone, AddaRouter, App) {

"use strict";

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    function onDeviceReady(){

    FastClick.attach(document.body);


    var router = new AddaRouter();

    Backbone.View.prototype.goTo = function (loc) {
        router.navigate(loc, true);
    };

    Backbone.history.start({ silent: true });

    // check is the user is new. Is new then go to signup page
    window.localStorage.removeItem("isNew");
    if(!window.localStorage.getItem("isNew")){
        router.navigate('registration', true);
    }else{
        if(Api.createSession()){
            router.navigate('contacts', true);
        }else{
            router.navigate('registration', true);
        }
    }


   }


});
```

Note: if I keep anything outside require block it works on the device.

Comment: Have you tried sticking in a bunch of alert() statements to see where the code fails and running it on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's the name of one of the js files. It wasn't detected in the simulator since my filesystem is case insensitive.